# Is there a way to move the legend in a trackViewer lollipopPlot and/or change its orientation?

Tags: r, legend, r-grid

Is there any way to alter the position or orientation of a legend in a trackViewer lollipopPlot (or fudge something that performs the same function), so that it's on the side of the plot and directly labeling each level of the stack? I'm plotting the positions of SNPs in different samples and with the amount of samples and SNPs involved it's getting a bit hard to keep track of what is what.

For illustration, a simplified example of what I've got is this:

[image: A lollipop plot with three stacked samples, with the legend above the plot.]

(Code used to create this:)

```r
# set up features
chromosome.feature.test <- GRanges("test", IRanges(c(1), width=c(500), names=c("test")))
test.snps <- GRanges("test", IRanges(c(10, 10, 25, 150, 10, 450), width=1, names=c("C10A", "C10A", "A25G", "T150C", "C10A", "T450G"),
                           stack.factor=c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3", "test_snp_3")))
# set up visualization details
samples.palette.test <- list("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
names(samples.palette.test) <- c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3")
test.snps$color <- samples.palette.test[test.snps$stack.factor]
legend.test <- list(labels=c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3"),
               col="gray20", fill=sapply(samples.palette.test, `[`, 1))
# plot
lolliplot(test.snps, chromosome.feature.test, type="pie.stack", legend=legend.test, dashline.col="black")
```

and what I'd want is this:

[image: the same lollipop plot, now with the legend on the y axis, with each label on the height of the corresponding level in the stacked plot]

I can't see anything about changing the legend position to that degree in the [lollipopPlot vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/lollipopPlot.html#Add_a_legend) - am I overlooking something?

As far as I can see from [the code](https://github.com/jianhong/trackViewer/blob/devel/R/plotLollipops.R), it seems the legend uses `grid.legend`, so I've tried to kludge something together using that - not outputting the legend in the `lolliplot` command itself but layering it on with a separate viewport:

```r
# set up features
chromosome.feature.test <- GRanges("test", IRanges(c(1), width=c(500), names=c("test")))
test.snps <- GRanges("test", IRanges(c(10, 10, 25, 150, 10, 450), width=1, names=c("C10A", "C10A", "A25G", "T150C", "C10A", "T450G"),
                           stack.factor=c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3", "test_snp_3")))
# set up visualization details
samples.palette.test <- list("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")
names(samples.palette.test) <- c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3")
test.snps$color <- samples.palette.test[test.snps$stack.factor]
legend.test <- list(labels=c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3"),
               col="gray20", fill=sapply(samples.palette.test, `[`, 1))
# plot lolliplot
lolliplot(test.snps, chromosome.feature.test, type="pie.stack",dashline.col="black")
# set up legend fill params
gp <- legend.test[!names(legend.test) %in% c("labels")]
gp$fill <- gp$fill[order(names(gp$fill), decreasing=TRUE)]
class(gp) <- "gpar"
# plot legend
pushViewport(viewport(x=0.94, y=0.215))
grid.legend(labels=c("test_snp_1", "test_snp_2", "test_snp_3"), ncol=1, pch=21, vgap=0, gp=gp)
popViewport()
```

but getting it to line up with the levels feels rather fiddly to me:

[image: the same lollipop plot, now with the legend on the y axis, with each label roughly on the height of the corresponding level in the stacked plot]

Is there a better solution?